# Where to ask questions about pricing models?

Tags: discussion

A little while ago I asked this question on SuperUser:

https://superuser.com/questions/940355/how-to-create-a-data-series-for-exponential-decrease-diagram

I wanted to find a formula for pricing my products in spreadsheets, so that I could price them fairly such that the more usage would have more discount.

However, based on the answers, I found out that the resulting chart would be something like this:

[image]

Which is absolutely wrong. Because it financially means that "if you buy 4000 units you should pay more than when you purchase 8000 units". Of course it doesn't make sense. Now I'm trying to find the data series that can create an increasing amount of payment which results to a linear pattern. But I can't figure it out, and my mathematical knowledge is not helpful here.

Where can I ask questions of this kind?

Comment: economics.stackexchange? Although this is not macroeconomic, it's more business related.

Comment: By the way, the cost curve is too steep. When you double the volume, you should drop unit price by perhaps 10%, not much more.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, can you guide me in the right direction. What I want is to encourage customers to buy more. I don't know how to get to that aim though. I'd really appreciate it if you can give me a clue.

Comment: Possibly on-topic at http://startups.stackexchange.com/ Not sure though.